# How to get data sum in date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve specific data for a period and sum this data

Example data set:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow (
DT date,
Part_number varchAr(10),
sales_volume int
)
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-01','HDD','10000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-01','SDD','50000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-03','HDD','40000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-03','SDD','50000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-05','SDD','90000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-07','HDD','50000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-07','HDD','40000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-08','SDD','20000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-08','HDD','30000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-09','SDD','10000');
insert into stackoverflow values('2018-03-11','HDD','20000');

select * from stackoverflow;
```

This is the query I tried

```
SELECT DT
    ,Part_number
    ,sales_volume
    ,SUM(sales_volume) AS sum_sv
FROM stackoverflow
WHERE dt BETWEEN '2018-03-01'
        AND '2018-03-07'
GROUP BY DT
    ,Part_number
    ,sales_volume
HAVING Part_number = 'SDD'
ORDER BY Part_number;
```

The result of my query

```
2018-03-01  SDD 50000   50000
2018-03-03  SDD 50000   50000
2018-03-05  SDD 90000   90000
```

Desired output

```
DT          Part_number       sum_s/v
2018-03-05     SDD            190000
```

Comment: Remove `sales_volume` from the `group by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below query :

```
select max(DT) as DT, Part_number, sum(sales_volume) as sum_sv
  from stackoverflow
 where dt between '2018-03-01' and '2018-03-07'
   and Part_number = 'SDD'
 group by Part_number
 order by Part_number
```